# Single SQL query to display aggregate data while grouping by 3 fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table that contains basic info:

```
CREATE TABLE testing.testtable
(
  recordId serial NOT NULL,
  nameId integer,
  teamId integer,
  countryId integer,
  goals integer,
  outs integer,
  assists integer,
  win integer,
  sys_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT testtable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recordid)
)
```

I want one single SQL query, (with one record per person-team-country) to display the following data. Note that I want it to group by `nameId`, `teamId`, and `countryId`

- Name, Team, and Country
- Goal/out ratio `(G/O)`
- Goal + Assist / out ratio `(GA/O)`
- Win percentage `(Win%)`
- The difference between the current goal/out ratio and what it was one month ago `(rDif)`
- The difference between the current goal+assist/out ratio and what it was one month ago `(fDif)`
- The difference between the current win % and what it was one month ago `(winDif)`

Example Table with all records:

```
Id   nameId   teamId   countryId   goals outs assists  win  sys_time
1    1        3        5           2     4    11       1    2013-01-01
2    1        3        5           9     4    19       1    2013-01-01
3    1        3        4           10    2    1        0    2013-01-01
4    1        3        4           11    50   14       1    2013-01-01
5    2        2        2           10    5    4        1    2013-01-01
6    2        3        5           4     7    15       0    2013-01-01
7    1        3        5           4     8    22       0    2014-07-01
8    1        3        4           11    3    5        1    2014-07-01
9    3        1        4           44    1    4        1    2014-07-01
```

Example desired output record (1-3-5):

```
nameId   teamId   countryId   G/O    GA/O  Win%  rDif  fDif  winDif
1        3        5           0.938  4.19  66    0.44  0.94  -0.34
```

The ratios are easy enough to retrieve.. for the differences, I've done the following:

```
select tt.nameid
       avg(tt.goals) - avg(case when tt.sys_time <  date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '1 month') then tt.goals end) as change
from testing.testtable tt
group by tt.nameid
order by change desc
```

This works if I want the differences for only the nameIds. But I want it to pull one record for each combination of name-team-country. I can't seem to get that working.

Comment: you should be able to add to the grouping so `group by tt.nameid, tt.teamid, tt.countryid` did you try that? (also add them to the select) or is there something i'm missing here?

Comment: Include the additional columns (team_id and countryID) in your select and group by statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by multiple fields:

```
select tt.nameid, tt.teamID, tt.countryID,
       avg(tt.goals) - avg(case when tt.sys_time <  date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '1 month') then tt.goals end) as change
from testing.testtable tt
group by tt.nameid, tt.teamID, tt.countryID
order by change desc
```

Answer (score 0):

just off the top of my head I think it would work for you to use

```
group by tt.nameid, tt.teamId, tt.countryId
```